# In excel, return "true" if a sample has been repeated in a multiple of 2 times and at least one couple of replicates satisfies a condition

Tags: excel-formula

I have a situation in which I have a list of samples that have been run in previous experiments.

Each sample has to be repeated in 2 replicates.
Each *couple* of results can either produce a valid or invalid result. If it is invalid, the couple will have to be repeated.

How do I get Excel to return the text "true" if the sample has got a multiple of 2 replicates and at least one couple has returned a valid result?

Example:

S1 is repeated 4 times. The first two are invalid, but the third and fourth are valid, therefore "true".

S2 is valid, but is only run once, therefore "false".

S3 is invalid and has no second replicate, therefore "false".

S4 was repeated 6 times, a multiple of 2, but was only valid the last two times, "true".

S5 was repeated 6 times, a multiple of 2, but was never valid, "false".

S6 was repeated 5 times, one result is valid, but not a multiple of 2 results is valid,therefore "false".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use AND with MOD and COUNTIF(S).

```
=AND(MOD(COUNTIF(A:A,A1),2)=0,COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"Valid"))
```

[image]